# Alarm Code in java using Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, clock, alarm

Hi Guys First of all I must say thanks to all of you guys for helping me :). I was a silent member before this query and benefited a lot from other members question.

But now I'm stuck in my code. See I'm developing a software that will help EVENT MANAGEMENT. I have done all that basics of creating and saving events in the database - i'm using sqlite db.

I'm stuck for code of pop-up and alarm when event time is started.

I saved date as String in db which is in this format "26-04-2015".
I saved time as String in db which is in this format "17:00:00".

What I've tried uptil now is this - I was comparing current time with that on db but failed to make it work)

Any suggestion or help will be highly appreciated.

```
private void checkAlarm() {

    new Thread() {

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int sec = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        String time = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;

        String[] data = connect.readData1("Select e_sdate, e_stime,e_title from tbl_event order by e_sdate ASC limit 1", "e_stime", "e_title");
        String sTime = data[0];
        String title = data[1];


        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("time from db : " + sTime);
                    System.out.println("time current : " + time);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }


                if (time.equals("sTime")) {
                    try {
                        TrayIcon icon = new TrayIcon(getIconImage(), "Event Management System", createPopupMenu());
                        playSound();
                        icon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This event has been started now.");
                            }
                        });
                        SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(icon);
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        icon.displayMessage("Event : " +title, "Event Time : " +sTime, TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Tray Icon Error : " +e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```